# python syntax error comparision operator

Tags: python

I am running an elif loop but whenever i run this line of code it gives me the error message I can't find the syntax error here

```
elif (rand_num-10)<=guess_num<=rand_num or rand_num<=guess_num<=(rand_num+10)
```

the error message is

> elif (rand_num-10)<=guess_num<=rand_num or rand_num<=guess_num<=(rand_num+10)
>                                                                                   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Missing colon on at the end of the clause?

Comment: We can't really tell without the proper context to reproduce the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `:` after elif and condition.

```
rand_num = 2
guess_num = 3
rand_num = 4


if rand_num < 3:
    pass
elif (rand_num - 10) <= guess_num <= rand_num or rand_num <= guess_num <= (rand_num + 10):
    print('working')
else:
    print('not working')

# prints working
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problems is with the colons at the end

> :

Comment: This is incorrect. Chained comparison operators are perfectly valid in python.

Comment: Just realized what's wrong